# Repair GRUB on Ubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

What can i do if I do not get a prompt as to which OS to choose (WINDOWS 10 or UBUNTU) while my laptop boots up?
(Problem with GRUB)

I have Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: have you run the command `sudo update-grub`?

Answer (score 1):

For a working grub you should install Ubuntu over Windows otherwise if you install Windows over Ubuntu then it overwrite grub and boot directly to Windows without showing if Ubuntu is installed on the system. 
For proper working of grub you can reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Bootloader is overridden by grub when you install Ubuntu.And when you delete grub there is no bootloader to boot any of the os so bring back grub ,Do the following

Boot using a live usb/cd of ubuntu. 
Use `boot-repair` to fix the problem.

After booting with live usb/cd, run following command in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Use `Recomended Repair`.

[image]

[**More Information**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

Boot-Repair requests to open a terminal and type three commands. 
This one does not work:

```
sudo dpkg -configure -a    
    error Unknown option -o
```

The correct command is

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```